# how to debug jquery loop?

Tags: jquery, debugging, loops

I would like to know how I can debug a jQuery/javascript code. I'm having a hard time wondering how the code runs through `.each()` loop and so on. Most of the time, I need to know what values the variables are holding.

I remember C++ have some nice debugging tools that allow me to run the code line by line.
What debugging tools should I use for jQuery or javascript? and where can I learn to use them?

FYI, my javascript and html codes are in a python script. Should I use a python debugger instead?

EDIT: I'm using Python IDLE to write all my codes. Sometimes i test them in Fiddle too.

Comment: Try using Chrome Dev tool, Firebug etc.. https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: BTW: It will also help you to use the full-text version of jQuery instead of a minified one if you want to step through the code.

Comment: thanks guys, will find out more about Firebug :D

Answer (score 2):

Set a breakpoint in your developer tools or simply type `debugger;` where you want your code to halt its execution and open the debugger.

You can then step through, over, in, out your code.

Comment: I'm using python IDLE though... is there better tools for javascript tgt with python? 
thanks +1 :D

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(myvar);
```

Your browser probably has some more advanced debugging tools, but I've found simple console logging to be adequate for me.

Comment: thanks! +1 :)
hmm as i'm using python IDLE and normal CMD, i'm not sure whr to look our for the display of console.log() ... so far, i've never seen it appear on my screen although i added that everywhere last time.

Comment: @yvonnezoe console.log() will attempt to log to the browser console. Your IDE may have its own console, but you'd have to check the documentation. In JavaScript you can check if console exists as easily with `if ('console' in window)` or something like that.

Comment: :) ohh i will look into that. thank you! +1 for taking your time to explain to me:)

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to use a javascript debugger, not python.
I'm not a web-dev by trade but the few times I've needed to do anything google chrome has been enough.

right-click -> inspect element -> source -> set breakpoints

Comment: Thanks +1 :)
I can set breakpoints in my python IDLE but not sure how it is going to run the javascript.

Comment: Is it only for chrome and firefox? :s if my system is a linux which only supports Midori, then it's helpless?

Comment: I don't know, I've never used them